# How to scrape website with login required - example.com

Tags: c#, .net, scrape

I try to screen scrape a website using .net (Webclient, webrequest,response etc.)
I've tried many methods but nothing seems to work.

I always get "Please login to see this content!" site instead of 
full auction info : http://www.example.com/en/auctions/auto-details/107891/

i am sending login data with post method

Please help

Comment: Maybe herptyderpty.com don't want you scraping their web site? If you are authorised to retrieve their data within your app then I would approach them for an API to do so.

Comment: -1 surely you can phrase this in a way that does not list someone's website...unless it is your website and you should state that...

Comment: @Lazarus, you should probably remove that domain name from your comment (it has already been removed from the question.)

Answer (score 2):

Its because when you view it through your browser the authentication cookie is being sent to squiddlydoo.com so that it knows you're logged in (or whatever) and show you the content.

The webClient isn't doing this - so you're not logged in.

You'll have to capture the cookie somehow (if you're allowed to do this you will be able to) and send it off in the headers when making your request

Comment: While your answer is correct, I dispute that you can only capture the cookie "if you're allowed". It's possible allowed or not, is it ethical then no. Anyone who wants to allow you to pull data from their site freely is unlikely to require you to log in to see it in the first place ;)

Comment: I agree with your comment - I was merely trying to get the point across that if you are authenticated (i.e. you have a cookie) then it will be easier and ethical and therefore they will be able to

Comment: perhaps linking to another question on how to capture cookies from the local machine (never done it so im guessing) might be helpful to the OP?

Answer (score 0):

There are also legitimate reasons for scraping. For instance we run a 3rd party web app on our intranet. I need to make a quick API for some simple tasks. It does require to login.
Nothing fishy there. I think the term "Scraping" implies a negative spin on what is really just legitimate http interaction between 2 computers. 
Hackers code so coding is Hacking? I've worked for large fortune 500 corporations and seen them running a Macro Recorder program to batch access information from an old legacy DOS app. 
Sometimes you are asked to create fast APIs or in some instances the only API possible.